# How to rename Angular Universal entry file to app.js and move it to the app root directory

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

So I have an `Angular Universal SSR` app which runs with node. The latest Angular and Universal versions as of 21/01/2021.

My hosting company allows me to run nodejs apps on my shared cPanel, so I would like to run my Angular app there. But the problem is they only accept the entry file `app.js`.

But when Angular SSR is built, it outputs this:

```
app-name
    -> browser
        - (all the browser files.)
    -> server
        -> main.js
```

Is it possible to output the `ng build:ssr` to this:

```
app-name
    -> browser
        - (all the browser files.)
    -> app.js
```

Then when I run the app it runs the default app.js entry file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in MyDevil hosting.
I use scripts to copy and change file name and I used new file to run application in production.

```
"copy-server": "copyfiles  -u 3 ./dist/project-folder/server/main.js ./dist/project-folder/server/mydevil/",
"rename-server": "renamer ./dist/project-folder/server/mydevil/main.js -r ./app.js",
```

Answer (score 0):

There is much more simpler way to do it in MyDevil hosting (but you can reuse it in your example too). Simply create an app.js file and import the file from the server, it will start the Angular SSR app. So in the root folder of your public_nodejs folder you should have app.js and next to it dist folder. That's all!

app.js

```js
import('./dist/<your-app>/server/index.mjs');
```

Replace **index.mjs** with your executable file. For Angular 17 there is **index.mjs** file. Restart your app and enjoy! :)